# Unable to pass/Insert multiple values in php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The query is not showing any error but if i try to insert 2 to 3 values it works but when i try for 8 values it does not please help:

```
 $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO cat_item (CAT_ID, ITEM_NAME, TYPE, PRICE, PREP_TIME, DESCREPTION, OFFER_STATUS, SLASHED_PICE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $ct_id,$item_name,$item_type,$item_nprice,$prep_time,$item_desc,$item_ofr_status,$item_oprice);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Nothing in your error logs?

Comment: Are you sure the data type match ?

Comment: I was thinking `CAT_ID` didn't sound like it would be a string.

Comment: It runs when i run in mysql terminal raw query

Comment: If you can insert 3 columns but not 4 it's likely that the value of your 4th column has a problem. Try putting a literal value (not a variable) into your `bind_param()` call so you can be sure there is no problem with the value. There might be a wrong type, or a constraint.